# Child and sibling processes from running tmux in zsh

Tags: process, tmux, fork

I am using `Ubuntu 22.04.1` on `WSL 2` (though the fact that it is `Unix` is only relevant for this question)

How come when we run `tmux` from a `zsh` session, the process tree (which I have abridged somewhat) changes from

```
init(Ubuntu)─┬─SessionLeader───Relay(9)─┬─ssh-agent
                                        └─zsh───pstree
```

to

```
init(Ubuntu)─┬─SessionLeader───Relay(9)─┬─ssh-agent
                                        ├─tmux: server───zsh───pstree
                                        └─zsh───tmux: client
```

Here, `pstree` is just the command that tells me the process tree, hence its presence above.

When we run `tmux` in `zsh`, what happens is that `zsh` runs `fork()` to create a fork process that is a child of `zsh` (that is, `tmux: client` above). I am not sure how `tmux: server`, a process that is sibling to the process that spawned it, comes to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the server, `tmux` forks itself twice so as to daemonize itself, detach itself for the  session it was started from.

The  child dies, the grand-child runs the server. That means the server has no parent.

Processes without parents are normally  adopted by `init`, the process of id 1. On Linux, some process can be nominated as a *child subreaper* using the `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` [`prctl()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) to take on that role for its descendants.

That or the equivalent for WSL is likely what you're observing here. That `Relay(9)` process is probably a *child subreaper* and has adopted that `tmux` server daemon.

You can tell who's the *child subreaper* in your ancestry with something like:

```
((zmodload zsh/system; sleep 0.2; echo $sysparams[ppid])&) | cat
```

I'd expect that to return the pid of the `Relay(9)` process.

You can follow what `tmux` does here  by running it under:

```
strace -fo log -e clone,exit_group,prctl tmux
```

And inspect the contents of the `log` file afterwards. You'll see something like:

```
3908  execve("/usr/bin/tmux", ["tmux"], 0x7fffd0c3e990 /* 50 vars */) = 0
3908  prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "tmux: client") = 0
```

The parent is the client.

```
3908  clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f54afe20a10) = 3909
3909  clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f54afe20a10) = 3910
```

Forked twice for the server.

```
3909  exit_group(0)                     = ?
```

Child terminates.

```
3910  prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "tmux: server") = 0
```

Grand child (which by that time has already lost its parent above and been adopted by the  *child subreaper*) runs the server.

```
[...]
3910  clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f54afe20a10) = 3911
3911  execve("/bin/zsh", ["-zsh"], 0x55bee5bdd170 /* 54 vars */) = 0
```

The server forks a process to run your `$SHELL` in the first pane.

Comment: When is `tmux: client` made?

Comment: Oh never mind I get it now.